# Error: Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\FooRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

After updating to `doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.1.2` I'm getting this error:

> Argument 1 passed to App\Repository\FooRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry, instance of Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry given, called in ...

My Repository looks like this:

```php
namespace App\Repository;

use App\Entity\Foo;
use Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepository;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;

class FooRepository extends ServiceEntityRepository
{
    public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $registry)
    {
        parent::__construct($registry, Foo::class);
    }
}
```

=> See my own answer below.

Answer (score 52):

Just change this `use` line from

```php
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
```

to

```php
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
```

Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-the-repository

Comment: This is not true, the answer is correct! I've just hit the same problem and changing the "use ..." line as stated in the answer solved it.

Comment: Oh amazing, running `composer update` on Symfony 4.4 bumps `doctrine/common` from  `2.x` to `3.0.2` - breaking all previously generated Repository classes without any notification. Just awesome. I love doing minor updates and having my codebase break.

Comment: @Roger I have the same issue, did you have other breaking changes please ?

Comment: @Roger if you use classes such as the above but do not pin the dependencies that provide them in your composer.json, you're asking for trouble.

Comment: @gregOire - but if you *did* pin them in composer.json, you got a very confusing version conflict on that minor update.